# Subdomain to another NS than domain NS

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I have a domain from netfirms, with nameserver on reliable dns. But one subdomain I wonna send to rackspace server.

So what I should do, change "A" of subdomain to IP of rackspace server or add rackspace ns to the list of reliable ns I already have for whole domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create an A record for your subdomain and point this to the IP address of your Rackspace Server

Comment: Nothing, already 2 days

Comment: @dynback.com Ok, your going to have to give us more to go on than that, can you ping the subdomain, what response do you get? What does your A record look like?

Comment: no ping. You can look - neogov.dynback.com. A looks like IP address - 173.203.226.206

Comment: @dynback.com Ok, so the A record is pointing to that IP, is that your rackspace servers IP?

Comment: yes, mine, i have no idea what to do next)) is it possible to check in some whois service, is it pointed right?

Comment: @dynback.com ok, so your subdomain is now pointing to your rackspace server, thats what you wanted. What do you want to do now, are you hosting a site on here? If so you need to configure your web server, your not really giving me enough detail of what you want to achieve here.

Comment: "what you want to achieve here"

i wonna achieve "ping neogov.dynback.com" that is resolved) 5 days already with setted A record and no resolving. While "ping dynback.com" resolves good.

Comment: @dynback.com if I ping  neogov.dynback.com I get a response from  173.203.226.206, what more do you want?

Comment: Sorry, that was strange problem, my city dns was not updating for 12 days ((